# Sharing ref usage twice in React Hook Forms 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm hoping I'm close to translating my old react hook forms to RHF7 but I'm stuck trying to share refs twice with 2 different inputs. Can someone help me finish this code...So I need a ref on both dobMonth and dobYear but I can't use the same ref twice so I need to create a second one but it won't let me.

```
  const dobMonthInput = useRef(null)
  const dobYearInput = useRef(null)

  const {
    register
  } = useForm()

  const { ref, ...rest } = register('dobMonth', {
    required: true,
    validate: (value) => validateDate(value, getValues),
    onChange: (e) => onChange(e),
  })
  /*const { ref, ...rest } = register('dobYear', {
    required: true,
    validate: (value) => validateDate(value, getValues),
    onChange: (e) => onChange(e),
  })*/


  ....



  <input
        name="dobDay"
        type="text"
        {...register('dobDay', {
            required: true,
            validate: (value) => validateDate(value, getValues),
            onChange: (e) => onChange(e),
        })}
  />

  <input
        name="dobMonth"
        type="text"
        {...rest}
        ref={(e) => {
            ref(e)
            dobMonthInput.current = e
        }}
  />
  <input
        name="dobYear"
        type="text"
        {...rest}
        ref={(e) => {
            ref(e)
            dobYearInput.current = e
        }}
  />
```

I eventually need to use `dobMonthInput.current.focus()` and `dobYearInput.current.focus()`

I get the error `Identifier 'ref' has already been declared` for obvious reasons but I don't know how to get around it.
Thanks

Comment: Your refs are already defined so you use them like this on your component: <component ref={dobYearInput}>

Comment: And then you use dobYearInput.current in your functions or wherever you need to access the refed component

Comment: dobMonth and dobYear share the same { ref, ...rest } and write the same value at the same time to the different input fields

Comment: @MomasVII If I correctly understand what you're saying. `X` and `Y` share ref `Z` which in turns changes the values of `element A` and `element B`? If so, let me know and I'll begin writing a solution

Comment: That's kind of whats happening now. Basically I can't add a second sharing of the ref to the year field because I've already done it once and I don't know how to duplicate and make it unique for each input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an issue with ref declaration between react hook refs which its assigned to the same input, you need to create ref but without using already assigned ref to another input.

The trick here to resolve issue:

```
  const dopMReg = register("dobMonth");
  const dopYReg = register("dobYear");
```

for example:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const dobMonthInput = useRef(null);
  const dobYearInput = useRef(null);
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    dobMonthInput.current.focus();
  }
  const dopMReg = register("dobMonth");
  const dopYReg = register("dobYear");

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        name="dobMonth"
        type="text"
        {...dopMReg}
        ref={(e) => {
          dopMReg.ref(e);
          dobMonthInput.current = e;
        }}
      />
      <input
        name="dobYear"
        type="text"
        {...dopYReg}
        ref={(e) => {
          dopYReg.ref(e);
          dobYearInput.current = e;
        }}
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

and this the [demo url](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-keldysh-uymsd)

Comment: Amazing help, thank you! Was stuck for hours on this

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this too:

```
  const dobYearInput = useRef(null)

  const {
    register
  } = useForm()

  const { ref:refDobMonth, ...restDobMonth } = register('dobMonth', {
    required: true,
    validate: (value) => validateDate(value, getValues),
    onChange: (e) => onChange(e),
  })
  const { ref:refDobYear, ...restDobYear } = register('dobYear', {
    required: true,
    validate: (value) => validateDate(value, getValues),
    onChange: (e) => onChange(e),
  })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).